# WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms

Tags: selenium, jenkins

While executing test on jenkins, I'm getting org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms exception. 
I've tried with different versions of selenium but still getting the same error. Currently using webdriver 2.41.0 version with FF 17 & 20.

It is an intermittent process i.e. not getting this exception on regular basis but once it comes then it repeats continuously.

I've also used driver.quit in the @After but there is no success.

Can someone let me know the solution for the same?

Comment: I suspect it's your versioning. The minimum FF version now is probably Firefox 24 (the latest ESR release of Firefox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update selenium version and then see if error solve or not. Updating version should solve error.

Comment: As per the new release, it should be resolved in 2.44.0 version but I'm still facing the same issue randomly.